# Version Conflict with BouncyCastle.Crypto?

Tags: powershell, pgp, openpgp

I am trying to decrypt a file in PowerShell "7.x".  I am explicitly using the `Unprotect-PGP` cmdlet, but the error message I am getting refers to the `Protect-PGP` cmdlet.  Only thing I can come up with is perhaps a `BouncyCastle.Crypto` Version Conflict but am really not sure...

Would really appreciate any help or brilliant ideas (even semi-brilliant will do)!!

#### STATEMENT ISSUED:

```
Unprotect-PGP -FilePathPrivate "G:\TEMP\secretkey.asc" -Password "XXXXXXXXX" -FolderPath "G:\TEMP\ABM\PROD_Test.csv.pgp" -OutputFolderPath "G:\TEMP\"
```

#### ERROR THROWN:

```
WARNING: Protect-PGP - Can't encrypt files because: Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'BouncyCastle.Crypto, Version=1.8.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0e99375e54769942'. Could not find or load a specific file. (0x80131621)"
```

#### ASSEMBLY INSTALLED:

```
PS C:\>     # List Bouncy Castle version currently loaded
>>     $assemblies = [System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
>>     $bouncyCastle = $assemblies | Where-Object { $_.ManifestModule.Name -eq "BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll" }
>>     $bouncyCastleVersion = $bouncyCastle.GetName().Version
>>     $bouncyCastleVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
1      8      8      0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you have another Module using an older version of that assembly causing this dependency issue. You can try restarting PowerShell, if you can, using the `-NoProfile` switch: `pwsh -NoProfile` and run the cmdlet again and see if it keeps failing. If it doesn't fail then you can assume there is some other Module using an older version of the same assembly causing this problem, possible solutions are to upgrade said Module assuming it is indeed using the newer version of the assembly.

Leaving that aside, you seem to have a typo in your use of input and output file, you're using `-FolderPath` and `-OutputFolderPath` when the parameters you should be using to decrypt a file are `-FilePath` and `-OutFilePath`.

Alternatively something that might work assuming the assembly didn't change in its usage is to use the `BouncyCastle.Crypto` assembly you already have loaded directly instead of the `Unprotect-PGP`, which for reference, in its latest version is using the version [`2.0.0` of `BouncyCastle.Cryptography`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle.Cryptography/2.2.0):

```bash
try {
    $key = [PgpCore.EncryptionKeys]::new(
        'G:\TEMP\secretkey.asc',
        'thePrivateKeyPasswordGoesHere')

    $pgp = [PgpCore.PGP]::new($key)

    $pgp.DecryptFile(
        'G:\TEMP\ABM\PROD_Test.csv.pgp',
        # change destination file path accordingly here:
        'G:\TEMP\PROD_Test-decrypted.csv')
}
finally {
    ${pgp}?.Dispose()
}
```

---

#### Update

Thanks to OP's feedback we could determine that the module causing conflicts in this case was the [Az Module](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/tree/feb25af45af6400d8d1c3289c7f3d678b57f78d8) using an older version of the assembly:

[image: github]

Comment: Hi Santiago.  And, thank you for jumping in!

Comment: Sorry, new to this thing.  I have noted the parameter changes, and will test.  However, I believe I have found the root of my problem.  Windows Controlled Folder Access was preventing me from updating the modules.  

Leave me with one last question.  I am using the modules Az.Accounts, Az.Keyvault and PSPGP.  There appears to be dependencies between these.  How do I know which versions are required of each, for them to work nicely together?

Comment: @KareltenHoope this isnt an easy problem to solve really, in some cases there is no solution to the problem, meaining, 2 modules can't be used together. The only  way to solve the problem here assuming you have the Az module up to date might be downgrading PSPGP module until there is an assembly match between modules unfortunately.